# Time Complexity of Triple Nest Loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, time-complexity, nested-loops

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    a[i]=0;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            a=3;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a triple nested loop. My book states that the running time is:
O(N) + O(N^2) = O(N^2)

Shouldn't it be O(N^3)? All 3 loops depend on each other. It will run for N*N*N times.

Comment: This isn't n^3 since the variable i is reused in the inner loop, making it n^2.

Comment: Not sure where they get the O(n) though.

Comment: No it's not.  The outermost loop and the second loop both use i.  When the second loop is done running, (O(n^2)), the outermost loop will exit.  Unless, of course, that's a typo...

Comment: @G.Bach - you should submit that as an answer.  You deserve the credit.

Comment: Also - if `a` is an array, then why is the innermost loop assigning it like an integer?

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan This doesn't look like the semantics of the code matter. It probably is an introductory example to big-O notation.

Comment: I made up the stuff inside the loop. lol

Comment: I believe there shouldn't be outermost braces. Thus you have one loop that fills a[] with zeroes, _followed_ by a double loop.

Answer (score 6):

It is because the loop `#1` and loop `#2` are using the same count variable, `i` during comparison.

At the end of the 2nd loop using `i`, the value of `i` is *n* which makes it break out of the outer loop as well. **One loop is completely redundant there.**

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x = 0;
    int n = 20;
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++) //this loop runs once
    {
        for(i=0; i<n; i++) //this loop runs n times
        {
            for(j=0; j<n; j++) //this loop also runs n times
            {
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", x);
}
```

It is in `O(N^2)` time that the whole is running.

**[Example](http://ideone.com/pOCTrU)**

Comment: I had to say that a good compiler will make this example in `O(n)`/`O(1)`, it will probably optimize the code and tier all the garbage away.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that they is an error in your book. You have to look at your code more deeply:
The two first loops use the same variable for the loop, so what will happen is the following:

after ther first bracket, i is equal to 0 and you go to the second loop. When the second loop ends the first one will end to because both loops use the condition i

Actually I don't see where the O(N) comes from but the global complexity should be of O(N^2)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't n^3 since the variable i is reused in the inner loop, making it n^2. Not sure where the book gets the O(n) in that though.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks. I can treat the 2 outer loops as one.